# How to extract all contents in p tag with lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

There are three `xyz` and two `<br>` tag in the following html fragment.
I want to parse it and extract all content in p tag.

```
import lxml.html
strings = """<p> xyz <br>　
xyz <br>　xyz  </p>"""
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(strings)
texts = root.xpath('//p')
for i,content in enumerate(texts):
    print(i,"    ",content.text)
```

The result isn't my desired.

```
0       xyz
```

How to extract all contents in p tag with lxml?
Why my codes can't extract all contents (three xyz) in p tag with lxml?

Comment: there's only one p element in you xml.

Comment: But the content contains three xyz,not one!?

Comment: Agreed. I don't know the lxml but you can use bs4 for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`content.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlMixin-class.html#text_content).) instead of `content.text`.

I get this output:

```
0       xyz 　
xyz 　xyz
```

`content.text` only gives you the `xyz` string that is an immediate child of `<p>`. The other two `xyz`:es are stored in the [`tail`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail) of each `<br>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know lxml but you can use bs4 for that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
strings = """<p> xyz <br>　
xyz <br>　xyz  </p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(strings, 'lxml')

for i, html in enumerate(soup.find_all('p')):
    print(i, html.text)
```

output:

```
0  xyz
xyz  xyz
```